# Can i change my random numbers in action script

Tags: flash, actionscript, action

hi everyone
i need to change the random numbers outputted in action script.
you will see im getting 5 random numbers for 5 different location but it is limiting the number per location.

```
_loc_2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
Cone.text = "" + _loc_2;
_loc_3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 5;
Ctwo.text = "" + _loc_3;
_loc_4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 9;
Cthree.text = "" + _loc_4;
_loc_5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 11;
Cfour.text = "" + _loc_5;
_loc_6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 13;
Cfive.text = "" + _loc_6;
```

i need to change it to this random 1 to 15 but without having duplicate numbers generated,

```
_loc_2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
Cone.text = "" + _loc_2;
_loc_3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
Ctwo.text = "" + _loc_3;
_loc_4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
Cthree.text = "" + _loc_4;
_loc_5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
Cfour.text = "" + _loc_5;
_loc_6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
Cfive.text = "" + _loc_6;
```

Can this be done in action script?

thanks in advance
dave

Answer (score 1):

So you want to generate the numbers 1-15 in random order with no duplicates?

There are probably quite a few ways to do this, but here's one off the top of my head:

```
var numberSource:Array = [];

function initArray(maxValue:int):void {
 for (var i:int = 0; i < maxValue; i++) {
  numberSource[i] = i + 1;
 }
}

function getNumber():int { 
 var index:int = int(Math.random * (numberSource.length - 1));
 return numberSource.splice(index, 1);
}
```

So you'd call initArray(15), then you'd call getNumber() and each time it will pop out one of your values and return it. You should never get a duplicate and you should eventually get every number. I haven't tested this so it's possible there's some sort of glitch in there, but this should at least give you a good place to start! :)